# Next sequence jumping issue in sql server for interger

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Getting a strange error while inserting data into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Requests](
    [RequestID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LRequestID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

AND I have one sp which will return the last inserted value into this table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSequenceValue]   
    @name as nvarchar(100)  
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @name=N'Request' SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[RequestNumber] AS [Value] 
END
```

Now I am using this sp to get the last inserted record and placing this value into the temptable to access this value. Surprisingly it is jumping the values.

i am doing in the below way.

```
   CREATE TABLE #tmpTableRequests
    (
        OutputValue VARCHAR(100)
    )
    INSERT INTO #tmpTableRequests (OutputValue)   
    declare @requestidjumpissue int
    EXEC GetSequenceValue'request'
    select @RequestIDForanothertable= OutputValue FROM #tmpTableRequests
        print @RequestIDForanothertable
```

But here it is jumping the values means if actually inserted value is 10 when i insert into the temp table is is displaying as 12.

Please suggest what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to do here. You seem to be mixing up sequences and identity columns - which are different things and sequences don't even exist in the 2008 product line. But its also unclear what goal you're trying to achieve or what your actual problem is.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:I am using 2008 R2 and my intention is while inserting bulk data i am writing lots fo identity statements to fetch the last inserted values , found that there is  sequence availble in sql server to fetch the last insert row, why i am using this is if i use the scope_identity(); it is working fine for me , but from the application in C# developers genarating sequencer to genarate the new id's.when i am providing my data from the database , and if they use the application id genaration process will be diffrent, so that trying to sync both database code and development code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution for this case.

Sequence genarator is providing an alternate approach to create the identity coloumns. If Iwant to get the last inserted coloumn we can go for this and it is so faster. THanks to sql 2008R2.
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSequenceValue]
    @name as nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
IF @name=N'Request' SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [dbo].[RequestNumber] AS [Value]
```

END